# Current timestamp relative time help :)

Tags: php, mysql

First off, I want to apologize beforehand, as I know there is a lot of information about this subject on the net. But this has been annoying me the whole day.

In my database (MySQL), I have comments stored with the time they have been written (by using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`). Now I would like to make a script that relates the time between the present and the time that a user wrote a comment (for instance "comment written 6 hours ago...").

But here's the thing, I have tried loads of different scripts and I'm always ending up with the same question. How do I convert my `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to the type of date the script wants me to use?

http://snipplr.com/view/4912/

In the link above there's a code, and you should define the variable with a date. Now, I have the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and it looks like this:  `2012-01-15 16:21:32`

Should I just do the date (2012-01-15 16:21:32)?

Sorry again, I know there's a lot of information about this on the web, but I've been working on this the whole day without results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I tried the format you had in the post and it worked.

Comment: $date = $data['comments'][0]->timeunix; 
This is my time that i got from the database..!

I put it in the function as $date...

This is what it says: onJanuary 1, 1970

Comment: ...why did you mark this as the correct answer?  Is your script working?

Comment: @rockerest, Question: `Should i just do date(2012-01-15 16:21:32)?` Answer: `Yes`

Comment: @Walkerneo That code returns `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER` so the correct answer is, `No`.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @rockerest, I assumed it was psuedo-code. Did you actually try that?

Answer (score 0):

Most scripts out there calculate with epoc time (seconds since 1970), so you'll need to convert the date to seconds then plug into the script: `$row['dateUNIX']`.

MySQL:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(myDateColumnName) as dateUNIX,* FROM `myTable`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the linked code for formatting, change this line

```
$diff = time() - strtotime($date);
```

to

```
$diff = time() - $date;
```

Do as matt has suggested above to get the timestamp of the comment then just:

```
$date = $row['dateUNIX'];
getRelativeTime($date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this script yet?

`$diff = time() - strtotime($date);` would take your `2012-01-15 16:21:32` and convert it to a useable epoch time.

The script works as intended, with your data, and no changes.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: Hey yeah i used the date 2012-01-15 16:21:32 and it worked, but when i use 2011-01-20 18:54:07 it says on January 1, 1970

Comment: @MathiasFyrstJakobsen Something is wrong with your code.  I tried `2011-01-20 18:54:07` and it printed `on January 20, 2011`.  Please check your inputs and try again.